# Confusing fraction indeterminate equation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The question is: find all integers $n$ that make $\dfrac{5n+6}{8n+7}$ an integer

The solution says that if the value of the given fraction becomes $k$ after simplification, $5l+6 = km$, $8l+7 = n$(where $m$ and $n$ are integers).

So, $5l-mk = -6$, $8l-nk = -7$.

Solving this gives you $k=13$, $8m-5n=1$, and the particular solution to this is $m=2, n=3$.

The general solution then is $m = 5q+2$, $n = 8q+2$($q$ is an integer). Therefore, $l = 6n-7m = 13q+4$.

So, at when $1 = 13q+4$, the given fraction becomes $13$.
(the solution and question have been translated from another language)

My issue with this solution is that they don't explain the first sentence, and the last answer given doesn't end up answering all integers $n$... could someone explain the given solution or an easier way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The solution as stated doesn't make sense to me. The first line should have $8l+y = m$, not $n$. $\quad$ As for an easier way, show that for all but finitely many integers $n$, the expression lies between two consecutive integers. It then remains to check those finitely many integers.

Comment: yeah that was what confused me because n is in the given fraction...

Answer (score 1):

Taking the first sentence alone, (5n+6)/(8n+7)=(an integer), there appears to be one integer solution, n=-1.
Substituting n=-1 the fraction value becomes
(6-5)/(7-8) = (1)/(-1) = -1.

By inspection of a few nearby consecutive "n" integer candidates; increasing as 0,1,2,3,4 etc and also decreasing as -2,-3,-4 etc, the calculated fraction tends to the value +5/8 as n changes in both directions.

I conclude therefore that the *question* has been wrongly translated from the original language. If we could "recreate" the original question then perhaps the answer with explanation as given would all drop into place and make sense.
Trying the possibility that "n" is intended to be a rational number (=l/m perhaps?) does make the question more interesting.